# Is there a way to suspend and resume Animation or AnimationSet in Android?

Tags: android, animation

Even when fragment's `onPause` fires running `Animation` or `AnimationSet` doesn't stop and continue animating on background. Is there a way to suspend animations in `onPause` or by other event and then to resume it by `onResume` or other corresponding event? Maybe by wrapping animation to a separate thread and then suspend that thread, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [cancel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#cancel%28%29) method of `Animation`. Just call it in your `onPause()`. You won't be able to resume it where it left off but you can either restart it or not show it when you come back to it.

Comment: actually I'm looking for a way to pause/resume animation not only by onPause/onResune but also and even more important by buttons.

Comment: You can achieve this the same way and call the `cancel()` method in your buttons `OnClickListener`. If you're looking for more advanced animation features, I recommend you take a look at the ObjectAnimator developer guide. It should provide all you need to "pause" and "resume" your animations. With this component, think about it as creating animations from one point to the other rather than pausing and resuming it. It's a bit trickier, but much more powerful than `Animation`

Answer (score 0):

You can track the current location of the view with an `AnimatorUpdateListener`:

```
animation.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener(){
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        //get animated value using
        animation.getAnimatedValue();
        animation.getCurrentPlayTime();

        //then handle the click listener
    }

});
```

If you save the current animation value and timestamp to variables, then pass them to the bundle in `onSavedInstanceState`, you can cancel the animation in `onPause`, then resume it at the saved values in `onRestoreInstanceState`.